# Rails engine 'require' prefix

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, path, rubygems, require, rails-engines

If i have a gem 'foo' (Which is engine-based), how can i say that all files included in it will need the 'foo/' prefix when 'require'ing them?

For instance, if in my 'foo' gem i have a 'bar.rb' file, i'd like to be able to force that the inclusion of this file are done like this:

```
require 'foo/bar'
```

instead of the usual

```
require 'bar'
```

i want this behavior to apply whatever the inclusion context is (From an APP, from another gem, etc)...

i know it's doable since most of rails files are included through the 'rails' prefix:

```
require 'rails/something'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that programatically other than manually specifying the prefix manually when the files are required. There's no way for Ruby to know other than if you tell it.

Comment: i didn't understand your answer, can you please be a bit more specific? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
Dir["/path/to/directory/*.rb"].each {|file| require file }
```

Just make sure you have your `foo` in the root directory and the rest of the files in the subdirectory (otherwise it'll include itself)

Comment: i feel like you're giving me the opposite answer (Include files from a folder), while i'm asking to be able to force developers who use my gem to specify a prefix for requiring a file in my gem. Or maybe am i mistaken?